# How to set Proxy Settings in Ant deployment

Tags: java, groovy, proxy, ant

I'm trying to build this project [groovyldap](https://dzone.com/articles/programming-ldap-groovy).

I believe I'm running into a proxy issue.

```bash
$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/user/Projects/groovyldap/build.xml

prepare:

resolve:
[ivy:retrieve] :: Apache Ivy 2.5.1 - 20221101102211 :: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.13/libexec/lib/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: Apache Directory Project#groovyldap;working@redacted.example.com
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 494ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: groovy#groovy;1.0
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    /Users/user/.ivy2/local/groovy/groovy/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact groovy#groovy;1.0!groovy.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    /Users/user/.ivy2/local/groovy/groovy/1.0/jars/groovy.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    /Users/user/.ivy2/shared/groovy/groovy/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact groovy#groovy;1.0!groovy.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    /Users/user/.ivy2/shared/groovy/groovy/1.0/jars/groovy.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy/1.0/groovy-1.0.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact groovy#groovy;1.0!groovy.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy/1.0/groovy-1.0.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: groovy#groovy;1.0: not found
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:retrieve]  Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy/1.0/groovy-1.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
[ivy:retrieve]  Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy/1.0/groovy-1.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/Projects/groovyldap/build.xml:43: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 1 second
```

How do I set a proxy in Ant deployment?

I was expecting Ant to use system environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/06/how-to-set-proxy-settings-in-ant.html).

Added the `<setproxy>` directive to the `resolve` target in `build.xml`.

```xml
<target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">
  <setproxy proxyhost="proxy.example.com" proxyport="8080" />
  <ivy:retrieve />
</target>
```